# Android: Adding Image to Master Detail Flow, scrolling text

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a information orientated app using the master/detail flow and so far, so good. I would like to add images to the TextView, but it's formatted differently then what I've experienced in the past and I'm lost. from my understanding of what I've read while searching is that the scrolling text is "newer" when generating the Master/detail activity, therefore I haven't found any information on this specific issue. I would also like to pass the images in using the content activity, so it would be-

```
addItem(new Item(ID,Name,Detail,Image1,Image2));
```

what the detail XML file looks like

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bobblehead_detail"
style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
tools:context="com.example.johnson.fallout4bobbleheadlocations.BobbleheadDetailFragment" />
```

I tried adding ImageView's under it, but I received errors.

tl;dr I would like to add 2 images under the scrolling TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I clearly understand what you mean but looking at your xml it seems to me that you need to add a layout (either relative or linear) to your xml file and then add a textview and two imageviews (or whatever you want) into that layout. 
Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp" tools:context="com.example.somefragment">
<TextView 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/some_id2"
 android:text="Here is your text"/>
 <ImageView 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/some_id"
 android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
 <ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/some_id3"
 android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know if it works, Thank you.
Basically, when you create a master/flow in Studio it produces the XML that I posted, which doesn't have a layout because it "seems" to be two layouts merged into one, one for the action bar and one for the content. I would like to add pictures under the text of the detail fragment.

I know when I made a Master/flow in an older version of eclipse it wasn't generated how it is now. And I can't find any tutorials on the new way studio does it.

Comment: @JohnsonMighty yes android studio now creates two layouts for each activity not just for master/detail. the one is for actionbar/toolbar and slidemenu etc, the other is for your content. In case of master/detail I guess android studio gives a layout with a simple textview as it assumes you will be providing a textbased explanation or detail regarding a specific item. If you want something more than that, you need to modify the content-layout to one which suits your needs.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked, thank you. I ended up going with a LinearLayout and once I set orientation all is well.

Comment: @JohnsonMighty glade to know that your problem was solved. If your think this was the correct answer you should accept it as "Answer" so that it will be of help to others.